# Fetching comments with user profile pictures from youtube videos

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

Im working on a plugin that fetches the comments from a youtube video and upload them into wordpress database

Ive found fw solutions for fetching just comment text and user names from youtube in SO, but currently youtube is using v3 which has no client library available for production use.

and I didnt not find any work around to get pictures of users(from my search), had someone worked on this or know any possible solution for this?

Comment: ah, my concern is not about code, Im worried about client-library of current API from youtube, and the possibility of fetching users pictures from the comment list.

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

Comment: do you see any download link there? Im not finding any link there

Comment: Please check my answer to your question, I think this library will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the library I mentioned before in my comment above here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation#obtaining

You can use composer to install the library:

```
"require": {
  "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
}
```

And then run `composer update`

Hope this helps.